# Add AzureApplicationID to Active Directory Group with SamAccountName

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-data-factory

I have give access to Azure Active Directory Group to a path on a Datalake.
I would like to give access to my Datafactory to this path.
So, I would like to add the application ID to Azure Active Directory Group.
My helpdesk team ask me for the SamAccountName.
I don't know what to answer to the Helpdesk Team.

Could you help me ?

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: Hello, Sorry, I have managed the subject differently, the problem was to deal with a team who use the on prem tools (dsa.Msc) to manage usage in AAD....

Answer (score 0):

The `sAMAccountName` is in on-premise AD, in Azure AD, there is no `sAMAccountName`. (There is an `onPremisesSamAccountName` of [`User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta#properties) object, not sure if your helpdesk team points it).

If you want to add the AD App(service principal) to the AAD Group, the service principal name or the application id is enough.

Navigate to the specific group in the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `Members` -> `Add members` -> search for the `service principal name or the application id` -> `Select`.